# Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy

There are two arrays: `a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`and `b=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`
A new array is created containing the other two arrays: `c=np.array([[a],[b]])`.

We want to threshold every of the two arrays separetely in the `c` with a min value(e.g. the value 3) and at the end to have: `d=[[4,5],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]`.

Following that way:

```
d=[]
p=-1
for i in range(0,1):
    p=p+1
    d[p]=c[i][(c[i]>3)]]
```

gives the mentioned in title error.
It will be nice to understand the reason.

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly, please fix it

Comment: @TimCastelijns you mean my loop is not correct?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it's not indented correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you have added an extra level of `[]` in `c`, so instead of accessing just `c[i]` you should access `c[i][0]`:

```
>>> for x in c:
...     print x
...     
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])] 
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Replacing `c[i]` with `c[i][0]` will fix your code, and also you cannot assign anything to an empty list so replace `d[p]` with an append call:

```
>>> d = []
>>> for i in range(len(c)):
    d.append(c[i][0][c[i][0]>3])
...     
>>> d
[array([4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]

#or simply:
>>> [x[0][x[0]>3] for x in c]
[array([4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Changing `c`'s initialization:

```
>>> c = np.array([a, b])
>>> [x[x>3] for x in c]
[array([4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Comment: @Aswini The same error is happening when I run the [x[x>3] for x in c] instead of [x[0][x[0]>3] for x in c]. However you explained it at the beginning of the post but did not fully understand. Can you please recommend me link so as to read and be able to understand?

Comment: @DimKoim When I used `[x[x>3] for x in c]` I initialized `c` differently: `c = np.array([a, b])`. If you do that as well then you  won't get such errors.